# GCC segfault caused by "optimised out" value in MATLAB MEX function

Tags: c, matlab, gcc, segmentation-fault, mex

I am trying to write a fairly simple recursive floodfill algorithm (to be run as a MATLAB mex function), but have run into an issue when turning on optimisation flags in GCC (v 7.5.0 if it matters). The code works fine without any optimisation flags turned on, but segfaults when I use the -O2 or -O3 flags. I've narrowed the culprit down to an index variable that gets optimised out by GCC -- if I specify it as a volatile variable, the segfault doesn't occur even on higher optimisation levels. I assume I must be using undefined behaviour, but I cannot see where this might be occurring.

The offending snippet of code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include <string.h>

//     Removing this causes the program to segfault -----v
void fill(double *image, signed int x, signed int n, volatile signed int i, double k)
{
    image[i] = k;
    if ((i-1) >= 0 && ((i-1) % x) < (i % x) && image[i-1]==1)
        fill(image,x,n,i-1,k);
    if ((i-x) >= 0 && image[i-x]==1)
        fill(image,x,n,i-x,k);
    if ((i+1) < n && ((i+1) % x) > (i % x) && image[i+1]==1)
        fill(image,x,n,i+1,k);
    if ((i+x) < n && image[i+x]==1)
        fill(image,x,n,i+x,k);
}

// image is a 1D array holding a 2D image of size <x,y>
void flood(double *image, signed int x, signed int y)
{
    signed int n = x*y;
    signed int i = 0;
    double k = 2;

    while (i < n)
    {
        while(i<n && image[i] != 1) ++i;
        if(i>=n) return;
        fill(image,y,n,i,k);
        ++k;
        ++i;
    }
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int n;
    double *image;
    size_t x, y;

    if(nrhs!=1)
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("floodfill:nrhs","One input required.");
    }

    if(nlhs!=1)
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("floodfill:nlhs","One output required.");
    }

    if( !mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) || 
        mxIsComplex(prhs[0]))
    {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("floodfill:doubleMatrix","Input 1 must be real double matrix.");
    }

    x = mxGetM(prhs[0]);
    y = mxGetN(prhs[0]);
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix( (mwSize)x, (mwSize)y, mxREAL);
    image = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    memcpy(image,mxGetPr(prhs[0]),sizeof(double)*x*y);

    flood(image,y,x);
}
```

The boilerplate at the end is to allow compilation and data passing from MATLAB (this is for a MATLAB MEX function). GDB and Valgrind both say the segfault occurs within the `fill` function, but don't specify where exactly -- I have to call this from MATLAB, and so the outputs are a bit confusing. Valgrind states that the reason for the segfault is "Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x27E33F70".

As far as I can tell, the code *shouldn't* segfault -- I am always bounds-checking before accessing the array `image`, and the array is created with size `x*y==n`. The thing that is confusing me most is the fact that the code works fine if I specify `i` as `volatile`, which suggests that GCC is potentially optimising away one of my bounds checks. I realise that I could just leave this as is, but I worry that this might be indicative of a larger issue that could come back to bite me later.

As an addendum, I have tried stripping out the MATLAB code and running it outside of MATLAB, but this causes the issue to no longer occur. I don't know if the added code makes GCC compile it differently. This isn't a solution though, as it needs to be run from inside MATLAB.

Comment: If we have to seek an operator-precedence chart to decode `if (i-1>=0 && (i-1)%x<i%x && image[i-1]==1)` it might be good to add some parens (and whitespace). It's certainly odd that `volatile` has any impact on a scalar function parameter.

Comment: Fair comment. I've clarified the boolean statements, but sadly it doesn't explain the segfault issue.

Comment: I don't know how in the world you thought to try *volatile* to sort this out, but kudos for that. Does it matter that the first *call* to `flood` passes parameters as y/x but the actual function has them x/y ?

Comment: When I was trying to debug the program with GDB, it kept telling me that `i` was optimised out -- I tried adding volatile so that it wouldn't optimise it out so that I could figure out what it was actually doing to cause a segfault, but when I added it, it stopped segfaulting. Fun. The reason for the switch between `x` and `y` is due to the way that MATLAB arranges its memory, and was basically to ensure that I remembered this.

Comment: Looking at the convolutions it might even be easier to read the assembler :-)   If I were trying to solve this problem, I'd be adding `assert()` pretty much *everywhere* in the `fill()` function. Before the first assignment: `assert(image != 0 && i >= 0  && i < n)`;, then pretty much before each recursive call.  If one of these were (for instance) going negative due to something we're all overlooking, this would catch it. "An assertion failed is an hour saved" - me

Comment: My guess is that this has to do with the stack overflowing (appropriate!) because of the excessive recursivity, and somehow making that variable volatile changes how the recursive function is optimized. Try to use your own stack for this, rather than the system stack. Also, compiling with ASan will help you immensely (add the `-fsanitize=address` flag to GCC).

Comment: How big is `x*y` normally? This might weigh into @CrisLuengo's helpful input.

Comment: I did some simple testing with x=100 y=200, and this went `n` recursive levels deep, and this feels wrong.  @CrisLuengo is right, this is a stack issue, but it might be solvable by changing the algorithm around. Is there a non-recursive mechanism?  But it certainly does not explain the `volatile` mystery...

Comment: It seems like it might be a bit of a mission to get ASAN to work nicely with MATLAB -- I'll see what I can manage. @SteveFriedl regarding the size, typically x and y are on the order of 2000-4000 (about 9 million pixels total); however, the data is such that the largest region to be filled has only ~300 pixels. I certainly *could* write it as a non-recursive algorithm (although it complicates matters significantly) -- the things is, though, the algorithm works perfectly either with `volatile`, or without optimisations. I just don't really know why.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Okay, I got ASAN to work -- you were right, it is a stack-overflow. The question remains *why* though. Any of the following cause the code to run correctly: compiling without optimisations; setting `i` to `volatile`; adding `printf(stderr,"%d\n",i);` to the `fill` function; adding `printf(stderr,"%.0f\n",k);` to the `fill` function **(???)**.

Comment: @MrAzzaman - I suppose that looking at the assembler might give you a hint; perhaps `volatile` changes the stack depth which means that the "working" version used a few bytes less per recursive call, enough to not blow the stack inside of Matlab, and it's just a matter of picking a high enough `x*y` to blow out any version.

Comment: @SteveFriedl You may be right. Certainly a pathological case of a 2000x4000 image consisting of all ones blew up even the "working" version. I will try CrisLuengo's suggestion of making my own stack.

Comment: @CrisLuengo - recommend you summarize all these comments and propose as an answer - you saw the stack overflow first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, compiling with the AddressSanitizer turned on is a much better way of finding hints of the problem than running the program through the debugger. Simply add `-fsanitize=address` to the GCC command line. You might need to pre-load the ASan library when starting MATLAB: `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/asan/runtime/lib matlab`.

My hunch, since there doesn't seem to be a way to index out of bounds, is that the problem is a stack overflow. A [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225770/gcc-segfault-caused-by-optimised-out-value-in-matlab-mex-function?noredirect=1#comment110053561_62225770) confirms this, though the reason this appears is hard to understand. Adding the `volatile` parameter, or a `printf` statement, greatly affect how the optimizer can change the generated assembly.

One should never blame the compiler until all other explanations have been exhausted. But it certainly is one possibility for this behaviour to be caused by a bug in the compiler. If there's an issue with the code, I'm not seeing it.

On the other hand, it usually is a much better to write the flood-fill algorithm using your own stack in a non-recursive function. I find that it makes code more efficient as well as easier to read.

Comment: Why would you need your own stack if it's non recursive?

Comment: @Steve: you end up doing the same thing, but instead of a recursive function, you have a stack and a loop where process the pixels on the stack and add new ones to it. The flood fill needs to propagate recursively, but you don't need a recursive function to do so, all you need is the stack.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now. I hadn't really looked into details of flood fill, but see that it's got to have a stack one way or another. Thank you.